# How to change from CChar to Data in swift 3

Tags: swift

I am facing a problem to change CChar to Data under GBK encoding.  Can some one give me some hint of how to do it, it would help a lot
The syntax seemed to changed so I am a bit stumped on how to do it

the before was changed to NSData but since the syntax has been changed to Data, I am not very sure on how to do the exchange.

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringENcoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))
let ccharStr = "aaa".cString(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: enc))!
let tmp = NSData(bytes: ccharStr, length: ccharStr.count)
self.writeValue(tmp)
```

now I have changed to

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))

let aaa = "aaa\n"
var stringCChar = aaa.cString(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: enc))
let stringData = Data(bytes: &stringCChar, count: (stringCChar?.count)!) // but this exchange can't show the correct result...
self.writeValue(stringData)
```

can anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in

```
let stringData = Data(bytes: &stringCChar, count: (stringCChar?.count)!)
```

is that you are passing the address of an *optional* to the `Data`
constructor, which means that the memory contents of the `struct Optional` is read, not the character data.

So you have to unwrap `stringCChar`, e.g. with optional binding:

```
let str = "your String"

let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))

if let stringCChar = str.cString(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: enc)) {
    let stringData = Data(bytes: stringCChar, count: stringCChar.count)
    // ...
} else {
    // cannot encode string in GB_18030_2000
}
```

A slightly simpler solution is

```
let str = "your String"

let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))

if let stringData = str.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: enc)) {
    // ....
} else {
    // cannot encode string in GB_18030_2000
}
```

Just note that the first solution will include a trailing zero (the C string terminator) in the data, while the second solution doesn't.